# Expected identifier or '(' error in my IBAction?

Tags: objective-c

I have made an IBAction that should take me to www.google.com in Safari, but when I wrote it in, it gave me the error

> Expected identifier or '('

Here is the code from the .h file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@class AVCaptureSession, AVCaptureDevice;

@interface SignInViewController : UIViewController
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ZBarSDK.h"

@interface QRscannerThirdViewController : UIViewController            
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,ZBarReaderDelegate>{    
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *resultTextView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImagePickerController *imgPicker;

-(IBAction)StartScan:(id) sender;
-(IBAction)TakeInput;


-(IBAction)LaunchPayPal; 
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/private/etc/hosts"]]; 
     //This is where the error "Expected identifier or '('" shows up. 

@end
```

Comment: what the heck is this line `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/private/etc/hosts"]];` in the `@interface` scope?

Comment: Method names in Objective-C are conventionally named in `lowerCamelCase`, not `UpperCamelCase`. Some exceptions apply but generally speaking `lowerCamelCase` method names are the norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the 2 #import statements that you have just after @interface to the top of the file, and eliminate the duplicate UIKit import.

Next remove this line: `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/private/etc/hosts"]];`  That doesn't belong in your header file, it goes into  a method in the implementation (.m) file.

That should get you a little farther along.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. I had, by accident, put it into my .h file. I meant to put @"www.google.com" as I was trying something else to see if it would even work when I forgot to remove the /private/etc/hosts and add it in.

Comment: Thanks again, @Dave. Unfortunately, right after the [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]]; line, I get an error saying Expected identifier. I have moved the IBAction to my .m file instead of my .h file. I have gotten farther in my project.

Comment: would need more details.  You probably want `@"http://www.google.com"`, but that probably won't solve what you described.

Comment: I have exactly this in my .m file @Dave

Comment: -(IBAction)launchPayPal:(id) sender{
    
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]];
}    @Dave

Comment: Thanks for the help, Dave, as I have fixed my error. What I did not see was that there was an extra [ at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong here:

1. Method names should be `lowerCamelCase`. Some exceptions apply, such as if the method starts with a well-known acronym (e.g. `URLWithString` or `UTF8String`).
2. The `@interface` block is used to describe the interface to your class. This shouldn't contain any implementation details at all. Implementation details (that is, the actual code) go in a `@implementation` block.
3. You are using `URLWithString:` but you are not providing a URL string, you are providing a path string. You need to use `fileURLWithPath:` instead of `URLWithString:`.

To sum up, remove the code from your `@interface` block and move it to an `@implementation` block:

```
@implementation SignInViewController

- (IBAction) startScan:(id) sender
{
    // do stuff
}

- (IBAction) takeInput
{
    // do stuff
}

- (IBAction) launchPayPal
{
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/private/etc/hosts"]];
}
@end
```